# Titanium - make multiple annotation

Tags: iphone, ios, annotations, titanium, appcelerator

I am a beginner in Titanium Studio. I can able to open a mapview and can make a single annotation. How can I make multiple annotation on a mapview for the given latitudes and longitudes? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop for multiple annotation.

suppose you have a data array having elements { latitude, longitude, title }

```
var annotations = [];
 for ( var i = 0 ; i<data.length; i++ ) {

         // this section will create annotations and add them on the mapview
          var pin  = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation({
                   latitude:this.data[i].latitude,
                    longitude:this.data[i].longitude,
                    title:this.data[i].title,
                    animate:true
          });

           annotations[i] = pin;

           // suppose mapView is your map object
           mapView.addAnnotation(annotations[i]);
}
```

Comment: i am getting Invalid type passed to function. expected: NSDictionary, was: __NSArrayM  in -[TiMapView annotationFromArg:] (TiMapView.m:96) error

Comment: its solved now :D code is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128566/how-to-show-multiple-annotations-on-map