# Titanium: How to show multiple Annotations on Map?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Its mine 2nd day on Titanium SDK.

I want to show multiple annotations on the map. I have referred answers at SO but couldn't find fix !

I tried below code : -

```
// To create map
var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
        mapType: Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
        region:{latitude:33.74511, longitude:-84.38993, latitudeDelta:0.5, longitudeDelta:0.5},
        animate:true,
        regionFit:true,
        userLocation:true,
        annotations:[createAnnotations()],
        top:110,
        height:200
    });  

// CREATE ANNOTATIONS

function createAnnotations ()
{
    var annoatationData = [];
    for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
            var mountainView = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation(
            {
                latitude:37.390749,
                longitude:-122.081651,
                title:"Appcelerator Headquarters",
                subtitle:'Mountain View, CA',
                pincolor: isAndroid ? "orange" : Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
                animate:true,
                myid:i // CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE THAT IS PASSED INTO EVENT OBJECTS
            });

      annoatationData.push(mountainView);
    };  

    return annoatationData ;
}
```

But I am getting this error

> [ERROR] Invalid type passed to function. expected: NSDictionary, was:
>   __NSArrayM  in -[TiMapView annotationFromArg:] (TiMapView.m:96)

Any suggestions ?

Thanks...

Comment: One thing to note: If you're using a custom view for your annotations, you must create an instance of that view for each annotation. I made the mistake of passing the same view to each annotation, and that made it so that only the last annotation was visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved !!!

Just replaced this line of code :

```
 annotations:[createAnnotations()],
```

with

```
 annotations:createAnnotations(),
```

Comment: and now accept it is best answer ;) You had a object in an object, that indeed doesn't work :)

Comment: @Topener how can I set region dynamic like say it should be same as my first annotation ?

Comment: please add another question to SO

Comment: It's typical JS. You'll have thousands like this one with titanium :)